# How to handle more than 50k records in lightning component

Tags: aura-handler

How can we handle more than 50k records without using any offset/pagination in lightning controller.We need to display more than 50k records in lightning component.Can any one has idea?

Comment: what do you want to do you want to count these record. because displaying these many records doesn't make any sense?

Comment: You can use lazy loading to get records and display them.  Might help you. https://newstechnologystuff.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/lightning-data-table-with-lazy-loading/

Comment: Lazy loading is displaying only 2000 records...after that i am getting error like soql offset can only retrieve 2k records.

Comment: just want to display the records and on selection of some records i am performing DML. so want to handle more than 50k records too.

Comment: any suggestions for the above question

Comment: You don't want to do this. Your performance will be abysmal, possibly to the point of being unusable. Browsers simply are not designed to handle that much data.